# Find whether a React component is being displayed or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to call a promise based function before dispatching an action to the store.
The problem is that I only want to call the function when the component is going to be displayed. I use a toggle action that turns the component on and off.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
if ( /*component is going to be displayed*/) {
  init().then(function() {
    store.dispatch(toggleSomething());
  });
}
else {
  store.dispatch(toggleSomething());
}
```

Action:

```
export const SomethingActions = {
  TOGGLE_SOMETHING: 'TOGGLE_SOMETHING'
};

export function toggleSomething() {
  return {
    type: SomethingActions.TOGGLE_SOMETHING
  };
}
```

Reducer:

```
export default function somethingState(state = defaultState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case somethingActions.TOGGLE_SOMETHING
    return Object.assign({}, state, { open: !state.open});

  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

part of the React component:

```
Something.propTypes = {
  display: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    display: state.something.open
  };
}
```

I basically want to know the value of open/display of the component above or another way to know whether the component is being displayed or not.
I don't want to pollute the render function or store a bool that changes every time I call dispatch.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Is the dispatch happening every time the component is toggled? Or only the first time the component is rendered?

Comment: It happens every time the component is being toggled

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of it, you'd want to take advantage of React's lifecycle methods. Particularly the [`componentWillMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentwillmount) and [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops).

`componentWillReceiveProps` does not get triggered for the initial render, so you may want to extract out the logic into a separate function so that it can be reused for both hooks:

```
function trigger(isDisplayed) {
  if (isDisplayed) {
    init().then(function() {
      store.dispatch(toggleSomething());
    });
  }
  else {
    store.dispatch(toggleSomething());
  }
}

componentWillMount() {
  trigger(this.props.display);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  trigger(nextProps.display);
}
```

Comment: Isn't that dispatching the action from within the component?
In that case, how is the trigger function going to be triggered as you need to dispatch the action to update the props.

Comment: You can dispatch actions from within components. The trigger function is going to be triggered because those functions run when React calls them. After taking a closer look at what you are doing though, you are going to end in an infinite loop. When it's first rendered it will call `toggleSomething()` which will then cause `componentWillReceiveProps` to be called which will in turn call `toggleSomething()` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: "The problem is that I only want to call the function when the component is going to be displayed"

A1: **This is definitely a problem for react lifecycle methods, in particular, componentWillMount() & componentDidMount()**

Q2: "I basically want to know the value of open/display of the component above or another way to know whether the component is being displayed or not."

A2: **The componentDidMount() method will be called when the component is rendered. To prevent an infinite loop where the component calls your promise on render just to call the promise again when the state changes, avoid including the toggled state in your component. Dispatch actions on component mounting that toggle the state in the store, but don't use this state in this component. This way you know whether the component is rendered without having the UI update. I hope that helps!**

```
import React from 'react';


class StackOverFlow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    toggleSomethingOn();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    toggleSomethingOff();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        The component has been rendered!
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function toggleSomethingOn() {
  //dispatches action to toggle state "open"
}

function toggleSomethingOff() {
  //dispatches action to toggle state "closed"
}

export default StackOverFlow;
```

A2: **If you are just looking to find out if a component has been rendered (outside of your code) you could go to your browser's developer tools and search the elements/DOM for your component html.**

Comment: toggleSomething in my case is going to dispatch the action to the store, hence render the component so it will cause an infinite loop

Comment: Got ya. Well then the state that is being updated/toggled must not be state that the component depends on. Dispatch an action on componentWillMount or componentDidMount that toggles a piece of state to the "open" position. Dispatch another action on componentWillUnmount that toggles that same piece of state to the "closed" position. If you separate this state property from the component (aka don't pass it in), then the UI will not re-render when the state changes. This way you don't have an infinite loop and you know when the component has rendered.